# Disable minor mode in specific major-modes or changing buffers (i.e. selectrum for prog-modes but not in shell)

Tags: completion, minor-mode

This is similar to many other questions but nothing is leaping out..

I'm a fan of [selectrum](https://github.com/raxod502/selectrum) (similar to helm and ido I gather):
e.g. hit `M-x` and start typing, it'll find matches and list them.

I'd like `selectrum-mode` enabled during all modes (at least prog-modes), but not during a shell (`M-x shell`); I'm fine with a specific list of modes to disable it (i.e. enable for all, then disable selectively) or enable for specific modes, i.e. it's handy during non-prog to `find-file` for opening, but when in shell I want regular shell (bash/etc) based tab completion to occur.

Simple enable of selectrum is:

```el
(selectrum-mode +1)
```

But this is global in all modes, all the time, so the simpler tab-completion goes instead to selectrum.

I tried putting it in an add-hook:

```el
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'selectrum-mode)
```

but this just enables it globally when first entering a prog-mode, I think; its not limited to prog modes. And really, I'd like it on all the time, barring some modes. The question is can selectrum be non-global at all, and even if it's a global-only minor mode, can it be toggled on and off automagically?

Without changing `selectrum-mode`'s code to be non-global (if that's possible), I wonder if there's a way to enable/disable it selectively per mode.

What is best practice?

If it's global, could it be toggled on and off when toggling buffers? Perhaps a code fragment to hook switching buffers and disable as appropriate; i.e. on switch buffer, check if entering the list of modes, and then check if `selectrum-mode` is on, and then `(selectrum-mode -1)` if needed. This seems cumbersome and likely there is a more elegant approach.

Your help is appreciated; always love to learn something!

edit: Noticed there is a hook `buffer-list-update-hook` which might be usable, so perhaps I'll learn enough elisp to build the if-mode-active disable code, but I'm sure there's a much more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

Attempting answering my own question:

**Try 1: partially works**, but as per comments below doesn't seem reliable

Create a wrapper global mode, that is selective about when it enables.

```el
(define-global-minor-mode my-global-selectrum-mode selectrum-mode
  (lambda ()
    (when (not (memq major-mode
                     (list 'shell-mode)))
      (selectrum-mode))))

(my-global-selectrum-mode 1)
```

**edit: Try 2:** Enable/disable the global minor mode on buffer changes

```el
;; turn selectrum on globally
(selectrum-mode +1)
;; Turn off selectrum on first entry into a new comint-mode (shell) buffer.
(add-hook 'comint-mode-hook (lambda () (selectrum-mode -1)))
;; Toggle selectrum after every buffer switch, avoiding the minibuffer.
(add-hook 'buffer-list-update-hook
          (lambda ()
            (unless (eq major-mode 'minibuffer-inactive-mode)
              (selectrum-mode (if (derived-mode-p 'comint-mode) -1 +1)))))
```

Stolen from:
https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2018-07/msg00002.html

Comment: Usually best to use `(derived-mode-p 'shell-mode)` to test a buffer's major mode, as that will also catch modes derived from `shell-mode`.

Comment: I also recommend using the `define-globalized-minor-mode` name, and being very clear about distinguishing between "globalized" modes and "global" modes, because they are very different concepts in practice.  (A "global" mode has no buffer-local state; a "globalized" mode comprises a "global" mode which controls (en-masse, in multiple buffers) the state of a "buffer-local" mode (which does the real work).

Comment: Hmm.  I don't think you've ended up with the right approach.  https://github.com/raxod502/selectrum/blob/3abbfd9bc7d8991cce20202942a5b59a6c8d8dab/selectrum.el#L2243-L2245 indicates that `selectrum-mode` is a regular global mode; either on or off, and not per-buffer; so your globalized mode is enabling a global minor mode, rather than a buffer-local minor mode.  That's not going to work out.

Comment: phils - I think you're right. So since its a on/off global, then what could be the approach? am I back to the (bad, maybe workable) idea of turning the global mode on or off on buffer change? Would that work or worth a shot? Or a better idea?

Comment: Updated my post with another possible solution. Pretty blunt, toggling the whole global minor-mode on and off on buffer changes but whatever gets me through the day at this point ;) (I think ivy is also global on/off, but I don't reliush going through ivy vs ido vs helm vs selectrum again)

Comment: There's no standard approach.  Global modes always need to be looked at on a case-by-case basis, as any given global mode might work in an extremely different way from others that you look at.  Perhaps there's a way to inhibit selectrum on a per-buffer basic, but you'd need to inspect the code to see how it actually worked in order to establish that.