# How can I turn off Company mode in only some major modes?

Tags: hooks, major-mode, company-mode, minor-mode

I use company when coding. I currently have it set to global. I would like to turn it off for a few major modes.

However, instead of turning it off globally, I only want to deactivate `company` for 2 or 3 modes.

I know I can use `(add-hook 'mode 'somthing)`

but, what do I need to put as the second argument to `add-hook` to turn off company?

Comment: Actually, there are several such duplicate questions. It seems this is the oldest one, and the others should be closed as dups of this one: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/62777/105

Comment: This one is older - it should probably be the one to keep: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/50339.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation of `company-mode` (`C-h f company-mode`)

> This is a minor mode.  If called interactively, toggle the
> ‘Company mode’ mode.  If the prefix argument is positive, enable
> the mode, and if it is zero or negative, disable the mode.

So, we use a hook

```lisp
  ;; enable company in all prog-mode based modes
  (add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'company-mode)
  ;; disable company in python-mode
  (add-hook 'python-mode-hook (lambda() (company-mode 0)))
```